# Notepad++ Regex command for deleting and replacing

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Could please someone write a regex command to **completely delete this**:

```
4512) SOME NAME
Unused 4512
```

So nothing is left? Not even empty line?

And another thing. I need to make this:

```
4875) SAME NAME
Used
7854) ANOTHER NAME
Used
74) NAME
Used
1) YET ANOTHER NAME
Used
```

Into this:

```
4875|7854|74|1
```

So I can just add "Unused (" at the start and ")" at the end to use it later in different text file to sort of compare used line's IDs.
So I'll just search for:

Unused (4875|7854|74|1)

Thank you very much.

Comment: You told us what you want to achieve, but not what your problem is.

Comment: I just need a regex command. I did have one that I made but I spent a long time creating it and it was really long but it did work. My HDD got corrupted and I lost text file where I had that regex command so I need a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1st part can be achieved by using the following regex:

```
\d+\)[^\r\n]*\s*Unused.*\s*
```

Replace each match with an empty string

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdX0VK/2)

**Explanation:**

- `\d+\)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit followed by a `)`
- `[^\r\n]*` - match 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a newline. This will match everything up until the next occurrence of newline.
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace(which include newlines)
- `Unused.*\s*` - matches `Unused` literally followed by 0 or more characters(all except newlines) followed by 0 or more whitespaces

The 2nd part can be achieved by using the following regex:

```
(\d+)\)[^\r\n]*\s*Used\s*
```

Replace each match with `$1|` or `\1|`. There will be an extra `|` in the end though.

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DdX0VK/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(\d+)` - matches 1+ occurrences of a digit and capture it as group 1
- `\)` - matches `)` literally
- `[^\r\n]*` - match 0+ occurrences of any character that is not a newline. This will match everything up until the next occurrence of newline.
- `\s*` - matches 0+ occurrences of a whitespace(which include newlines)
- `Used\s*` - matches `Used` literally followed by 0 or more whitespaces

Now, we are only left with an extra `|` in the end and add the text `Unused(` at the start and `)` in the end
For that, we can use this:

```
(.*)\|
```

and replace it with `Unused(\1)` as shown [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/DdX0VK/3)

Comment: You could replace `[^\r\n]*` with `.*` unless you've checked `. matches newline`. The parenthesis have to be escaped (in Notepad++) in the replacement part. It's better to use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement part.

Comment: This is an awesome answer :) Thank you. I'll try it later but I think it will work  perfectly.

Comment: Try this ------ Find what: `(\d{0})\)((.*\n){2})` and replace with: `$1|` ------- result will be, `4875|7854|74|1|`